# Find the index of a char in string?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a string that goes like `"abcdefg..."`

I would like to find the index where the letter **d** is at, so I can get the number **3**.

I managed to do it by looping through each letter in the string, but that doesn't sound very convenient. Is there another way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf.aspx) class exposes some methods to enable this, such as [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) and [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy.aspx), so that you may do this:

```
Dim myText = "abcde"
Dim dIndex = myText.IndexOf("d")
If (dIndex > -1) Then

End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Contanis occur if using the method of the present letter, and store the corresponding number using the IndexOf method, see example below.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myString As String = "abcdef"
    Dim numberString As String = String.Empty

    If myString.Contains("d") Then
        numberString = myString.IndexOf("d")
    End If
End Sub
```

Another sample with TextBox

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myString As String = "abcdef"
    Dim numberString As String = String.Empty

    If myString.Contains(me.TextBox1.Text) Then
        numberString = myString.IndexOf(Me.TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

```
"abcdefgh..".IndexOf("d")
```

returns 3

In general returns first occurrence index, if not present returns -1